# How to reproduce a request via cURL

Tags: forms, cookies, curl, firebug, query-string

I want to capture how parameters are being sent. Usually what I do is to make a request and check on Firebug's params tab what are the parameters sent. However, when I try to do this on the following site (http://www.infraero.gov.br/voos/index_2.aspx), it doesn't work - I can't see what are the parameters in order to repeat this request using curl. How can I get it? I'm not sure but I think that cookies are being used.

**EDIT**

I was able to get the request content, but couldn't understand it. It seems it uses javascript to generate the proper request. How can I reproduce this request via cURL?

Comment: They're using post... there wouldn't be any 'parameters. Use HTTPfox or firebug's 'net' tab to view the low level http communication and you'll see exactly what's going across the wire.

Comment: It just show the request header and not its content. How can I get the necessary information to replay this request via curl?

Comment: POST data goes in the body of the request, not the headers. e.g. look in HTTPFox's "Content" tab.

Comment: Ah, now I see the request content. However I can't understand what's going on there. It seems javascript is being used. How can I reproduce this request via cURL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see this previous question [cURL post data to asp.net page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384655/curl-post-data-to-asp-net-page) ? That might answer the question right there (all I did was search "ASP.NET cURL"). And this one: [Unable to load ASP.NET page using Python urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380638/unable-to-load-asp-net-page-using-python-urllib2) talks about Python, but it approaches it in a way that should translate to cURL.

But for my $0.02, I wouldn't bother trying to untangle ASP.NET's and __VIEWSTATE and javascript. Is it an absolute requirement that you use cURL?

I think you would be better off using a client that works more like a real browser and understands javascript. That's a bit of work, but it isn't as bad as it sounds.  I've done this before with http://watirwebdriver.com/ and a short Ruby script. Here's how to do it with [Python and Mechanize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116023/screenscaping-aspx-with-python-mechanize-javascript-form-submission) (this is probably a bit more lightweight).
http://phantomjs.org/ is another option that you script using javascript. If you Google "Scraping ASP.NET" you will see that this is a common problem.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how you want it done, but you can send the request with curl simply with curl -d name1=contents1&name2=contents2 [TARGETURL] etc.

Note that you probably first need to fetch the main page and extract the "__VIEWSTATE" form field and submit back that (VERY huge) contents to get your submission accepted.

Comment: Yes, I know how to curl a post request. I believe my problem is with that "__VIEWSTATE". I'm not used to ASP, so I have no idea what is it, or how to deal with it. Is there a 'shortcut' so I can send a request without going deep in learning it?

Comment: As it is filled in as a hidden form field you can assume your curl request needs to send it on. Just get the HTML page, extract the __VIEWSTATE value and pass it on in your curl request.